# Doxygen ignores tags

Tags: html, tags, documentation, doxygen

I'm new to doxygen so I have some problems.
I want to add tags like \param, \brief etc. to the documentation but for some reason, the generated html-page only shows the declaration of functions and classes but doesn't include any of the informations I put in my source-documentation.

Right now, the docu looks like this:

```cpp
/************************************************************************************
 * \fn  void Synthesizer::setDecay(float decayLength_ms);
 *
 * \brief   Sets the decay-parameter. The decay determines the length of a note.
 *
 *
 * \param   decay   The decay length in the scope [0,1]. Values outside this scope won't be catched.
************************************************************************************/
void setDexay(float decayLength_ms);
```

This is my doxygen config:

```
# Doxyfile 1.2.7 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# General configuration options
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
PROJECT_NAME           = Node 
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 1 
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       =  ../../Documentation/ 
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English 
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES 
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO 
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES 
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = YES 
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO 
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES 
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES 
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO 
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = NO 
STRIP_FROM_PATH        =  
INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO 
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = YES 
SOURCE_BROWSER         = NO 
INLINE_SOURCES         = NO 
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES 
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = YES 
SHORT_NAMES            = NO 
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO 
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES 
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES 
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO 
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES 
INLINE_INFO            = YES 
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES 
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO 
TAB_SIZE               = 8 
ENABLED_SECTIONS       =  
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES 
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES 
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES 
ALIASES                =  
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30 
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = NO 
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to warning and progress messages
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
QUIET                  = NO 
WARNINGS               = YES 
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES 
WARN_FORMAT            =  
WARN_LOGFILE           =  
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the input files
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
INPUT                  = . 
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.hpp *.h *.cpp 
RECURSIVE              = YES 
EXCLUDE                =  
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       =  
EXAMPLE_PATH           =  
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       =  
IMAGE_PATH             =  
INPUT_FILTER           =  
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the alphabetical class index
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = NO 
COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX    = 5 
IGNORE_PREFIX          =  
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the HTML output
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
GENERATE_HTML          = YES 
HTML_OUTPUT            =  
HTML_HEADER            =  
HTML_FOOTER            =  
HTML_STYLESHEET        =  
HTML_ALIGN_MEMBERS     = YES 
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO 
GENERATE_CHI           = NO 
BINARY_TOC             = NO 
TOC_EXPAND             = NO 
DISABLE_INDEX          = NO 
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 4 
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES 
TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the LaTeX output
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO 
LATEX_OUTPUT           =  
COMPACT_LATEX          = NO 
PAPER_TYPE             = a4wide 
EXTRA_PACKAGES         =  
LATEX_HEADER           =  
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = NO 
USE_PDFLATEX           = NO 
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the RTF output
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
GENERATE_RTF           = NO 
RTF_OUTPUT             =  
COMPACT_RTF            = NO 
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO 
RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE    =  
RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE    =  
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the man page output
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
GENERATE_MAN           = YES 
MAN_OUTPUT             =  
MAN_EXTENSION          =  
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the preprocessor   
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES 
MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO 
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO 
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = NO 
INCLUDE_PATH           =  
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  =  
PREDEFINED             =  
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      =   
TAGFILES               =  
GENERATE_TAGFILE       =  
ALLEXTERNALS           = NO 
PERL_PATH              =  
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the dot tool   
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
HAVE_DOT               = NO 
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES 
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES 
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES 
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES 
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES 
DOT_PATH               =  
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_WIDTH    = 1024 
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_HEIGHT   = 1024 
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES 
DOT_CLEANUP            = YES 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration::addtions related to the search engine   
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
SEARCHENGINE           = NO 
CGI_NAME               =  
CGI_URL                =  
DOC_URL                =  
DOC_ABSPATH            =  
BIN_ABSPATH            =  
EXT_DOC_PATHS          =
```

Do I miss something? Like I said, it generates every class with every function in the html page but they are not documented.

Thanks!

Comment: Please note that using \fn is not needed and even discouraged when the method you want to document is right after the comment (DRY principle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed something very fundamental.  The comment block **must** start with `/**` for doxygen to pick it up.

Two stars only. Three shalt thou not type, neither type thou one, excepting that thou then proceed to two. Seventy is right out.

(Hoping you've seen [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit_of_Caerbannog))

Comment: I don't know how I could have missed this. :D
(Nice quote btw. Shrubbery. ;D)

Comment: Ekke Ekke Ekke Ekke Ptangya Zoooooooom Boing Ni!